# What is the fallacy “X is bad, Y is worse, therefore X is not bad” called?

Tags: fallacies

I have often heard this type of argument:

> You are criticizing X using well-researched facts and arguments.

> Your interlocutor states that Y is much worse, with equally well-researched facts and arguments.

> Your interlocutor uses their argument that Y is worse to suggest that X is, in fact, good.

X and Y are linked in a general sense:

- two alternative medicines (homeopathy & chiropractics).
- two politicians (May & Corbyn).
- two historical figures (Hitler & Stalin).

This logical fallacy asserts that because Y is much worse than X, therefore X is good. What is this logical fallacy called?

---

Clearly in a binary choice, the lesser evil should win: X is bad, Y is worse therefore you should chose X. *⚠ This is **not** what this question is about.⚠* Please re-read the last sentence.

*This logical fallacy asserts that because Y is much worse than X, therefore X would be a good thing.* Not that it is a better choice, less-worst choice, the only choice but that it is a worthwhile choice on its own.

In addition, there might not be just two choices or one might not even be asked to make a choice: the fact that Y is worst makes X good regardless of X's merits.

Comment: Heh, I think I can guess what argument, in what debate, prompted this dictionary request. ;) (Perhaps Mika Brzezinski should read this.) *Though "before W must do X, all Y must do X" is a separate fallacy.*

Comment: This is related to the statistical "fallacy of the null hypothesis" . From http://www.americanscientist.org/issues/pub/2014/6/the-statistical-crisis-in-science/1: The idea is that when p is less than some prespecified value such as 0.05 [so "something significant happened"], the null hypothesis is rejected by the data, allowing researchers to claim strong evidence in favor of the alternative ["the something was caused by what we were testing"].

Comment: Sorry but your assertion is wrong for the example given. It is certainly possible and logical for 2 otherwise "bad things" when taken separately to actually have one of the options to be declared "good" when having to pick between them. Going to prison and being on parole are both very bad things but I would imagine that being put on parole is certainly a "good" thing versus being sent to prison. What your logical argument is missing is some other premise which sets the bar for "good".

Comment: Is this "whataboutery", or something similar to it?

Comment: I think the form of this argument we most often see is:  "X is bad." "Yeah, but Y is worse, so STFU about X."  The implied premise is that only the worst things should be condemned, or even rise to our notice at all.

Comment: @dunk The  question specifically **is not about binary choices**.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This is (at least a subset of) the **fallacy of relative privation**.

From [Wikipedia >> List of Fallacies >> Red herring fallacies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies#Red_herring_fallacies)

> Fallacy of relative privation ("not as bad as") – dismissing an
>   argument or complaint due to the existence of more important problems
>   in the world, regardless of whether those problems bear relevance to
>   the initial argument. For example, First World problem.

[RationalWiki](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Not_as_bad_as) adds

> [Use of this fallacy is] popular with people who know perfectly well
>   they're doing something wrong; being fully aware that they're doing
>   something wrong, they feel compelled to attempt to justify it and do
>   so by pointing to other (usually worse) actions.

A hypernym (again, [RationalWiki](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Moral_equivalence)) (emphasis mine) appears to be

> **Moral equivalence** is a form of equivocation and a fallacy of relevance often used in political debates. It seeks to draw
>   comparisons between different, often unrelated things, to make a point
>   that one is just as bad as the other or just as good as the other. It
>   may be used to draw attention to an unrelated issue by comparing it to
>   a well-known bad event, in an attempt to say one is as bad as the
>   other. *Or, it may be used in an attempt to claim one isn't as bad as
>   the other by comparison*. Drawing a moral equivalence in this way is a
>   logical fallacy.

Comment: In this case it's right on—and this is a good answer, +1—but, totally IMHO, I feel compelled to point out that RationalWiki is in general a pretty unreliable source. Good articles can be found, but much of it is of poor quality and not at all authoritative.There's plenty of outright nonsense there, and the community seems especially content to to let it stand.

Comment: Roses are sometimes found among thorns. But we should all be thankful to the person pointing out that we should be very wary of all those thorns.

Answer (score 24):

This seems like a **[false dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma)**:

- major premise: "either X is good and Y is bad, or X is bad and Y is good".
- minor premise: "Y is bad".
- conclusion: "X is good".

Because the major premise is fallacious, the syllogism (though perfectly valid) is not sound.

In your examples it's elaborated slightly: the interlocutors both seem to agree, on some level, that both X and Y are bad; but because Y is putatively worse than X, Y gets assigned the role of "bad" and X gets assigned the role of "good" in order to conform to the major premise.

Comment: (By the way, it's debatable whether this major premise really *is* wrong. If my choices are to lose a finger or to lose an entire hand, then while obviously losing a finger is bad compared to *not* losing a finger, it's *good* compared to losing an entire hand. The question is, what is our universe of discourse? If we have only two alternatives, then it's reasonable to say, for some purposes, that those two alternatives are our universe of discourse, and "good" and "bad" are relative to that. But that's neither here nor there.)

Comment: I think you mean the syllogism is perfectly valid, but not sound. An argument can't be both sound and not valid, since validity is a necessary prerequisite for soundness.


"Validity" means the structure of the argument is correct. Ie, _if_ the premises were true, _then_ the conclusion must follow.
"Soundness" is achieved by a valid argument that has true premises (and therefore a true conclusion).

Comment: @Oleksiy: Whoops, I'd thought they meant the reverse. Now fixed, thanks!

Comment: @ruakh: If there are no alternatives then it is **not** a false dilemma. It is just a dilemma. A false dilemma is when alternatives are hidden and an argument is made as if there is only the bad vs worse choice.

Comment: @slebetman: I think you're agreeing with my comment. Note that when I answered this question, it was on the English Language & Usage site, so I answered it accordingly: I supplied the appropriate terms to express the OP's argument, without regard for whether I agree with the argument. Since I didn't fully agree with the OP's argument, I noted that in a comment. Now that this has been migrated to the Philosophy site, I suppose my answer and comment could be swapped; but it's a bit late for that now. :-P

Answer (score 17):

If this logical fallacy is used as a retaliative defense, it is called [*tu quoque*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tu_quoque) ("you too").  You, who accuse me, do worse things than me; thus I am not bad. This doesn't cover all the instances, but it came to mind upon seeing Trump and Clinton in the question.

Comment: This is not an example of tu quoque. According to your link, "tu quoque" is a specific ad hominem dealing with hypocrisy. The claimant attacks a moral argument by pointing out that the arguments proponent does not always adhere to it's prescriptions.

Answer (score 7):

It's not an informal fallacy, it's a formal, logical one. It doesn't have a name, but perhaps should have a nickname because it is encountered so frequently lately. If you reduce it to form, you'll see it makes zero sense:

```
a is bad
b is double-bad
therefore,
 a is good
```

It's a failure of form (this argument can never be valid, no matter what the content), as its conclusion contradicts one of its premises.

Answer (score 3):

From this problem we can form two propositions:

```
1. A is good           - we'll call this 'G'
2. B is worse than A   - call this 'W'
```

From these propositions we can form three hypotheses and a conclusion, based on the original problem:

```
Hypothesis 1:   ¬G
Hypothesis 2:   W
Hypothesis 3:   W→G
Conclusion:     G
```

This is a *contradiction*, as `¬P∧P` can only ever equate to be false. Hypotheses 2 and 3 can be ignored - and logically, hypothesis 1 and the conclusion contradict.

> "A logical contradiction is the conjunction of a statement S and its denial not-S.   In logic, it is a fundamental law- the law of non contradiction- that a statement and its denial cannot both be true at the same time." - **G. Randolph Mayes** http://www.csus.edu/indiv/m/mayesgr/phl4/handouts/phl4contradiction.htm

Answer (score 0):

As all formal fallacies it's simply a [Non sequitur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_fallacy). Which is just fancy Latin for "it does not follow". So if the status of X as good/bad is unrelated to the status of Y good/better/bad/worse then the argument is invalid and from Y does not follow that X is good. Or in other words it's a logical fallacy.

Now of course natural language is a lot more vague and ambiguous than formal logic so whether that is a fallacy or just bad wording depends on context. As you already stated if this were a binary between X and Y then yes Y being worse would make X the better option.

Conversely if you make it appear to be a binary even if it isn't you create a [false dilemma/false dichotomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma). Another problem could be if you use "bad" in the sense of "the worst" (not limited to just two options, but expressing the top point of a scale), then of course showing that Y is worse puts X back in the middle field and not in the position of "the worst"/bad.
And if you are thinking "who would use bad in the sense of 'the worst'". Well as a matter of fact humans are largely monotasking so to tell someone is "bad" is often akin to giving it priority to be solved first, aka the most immanent problem or "the worst" (in that given situation). So showing that another problem is worse, might legitimately take attention from that. So while not good, it's good enough in comparison.

The thing is there is always the fallacy fallacy, where despite something being fallacious that still doesn't mean it's wrong. And especially in non binary situations fallacies are hardly applicable because it's usually well known that there is no perfect answer that you can deduce and that instead you're operating with heuristics and an inherent risk of being wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's to do with relativism.

If you only know X and Y, and know that Y is worse than X, then you have the situation described in the OP.

To know that X is bad, either you need to know about some "absolute" good (against which to compare X and find it bad), rather than mere "relative" good; or at least you need to know a third thing, Z, which is relatively good and compared to which X is bad.

In if you want to support your proposition that X is bad, in spite of your interlocutor's reminder that Y is worse, either you need to define what "absolute" good is or you need to explain what third choice you're comparing X with.

In your "homeopathy & chiropractics" example, you could argue:

- "My definition of 'absolute good' is a treatment proven via evidence-based medicine" (according to which absolute standard, both "homeopathy & chiropractics" fail)
- "My examples of 'relatively good' are e.g. vaccine and physical exercise" (compared with which, both "homeopathy & chiropractics" are relatively ineffective)

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Moderators (or the community) are welcome to delete this, if they agree with you that this does not answer the question. I was trying to explain the fallacy, rather than just name it: and explain how to escape the fallacy, or explain the miscommunication or assumptions which result in the fallacy.